# JOptionPane with multiple inputs

Tags: java, joptionpane

I need to get input in different ways using JOptionPane. Specifically, I need a dropdown menu along with the default input text field to both be present in the same JOptionPane. Is this achievable? if so, how?

Comment: The second parameter in most of the [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) static methods, like `showInputDialog()` is named _message_ and its type is `Object`. This means it can be **anything** including a `javax.swing.JPanel` which can contain an entire GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need different components in your `pane`, you can try to implement something like this:

```
JTextField firstName = new JTextField();
JTextField lastName = new JTextField();
JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
final JComponent[] inputs = new JComponent[] {
        new JLabel("First"),
        firstName,
        new JLabel("Last"),
        lastName,
        new JLabel("Password"),
        password
};
int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, inputs, "My custom dialog", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    System.out.println("You entered " +
            firstName.getText() + ", " +
            lastName.getText() + ", " +
            password.getText());
} else {
    System.out.println("User canceled / closed the dialog, result = " + result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped me think what the code would look like. Would you (or anyone) by any chance know how to implement a dropdown menu?

Comment: You can use a JCombobox for this.

Comment: @RoshanPrabhakar You should flag and accept the answer if you solved your problem, to help further readers.